# AMPPS Mac homeserver website not appearing in browser from other device then the server

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Ive set up a homeserver on a mac mini using Ampps. The server is working fine and Ive installed worpress for my website.

The thing is that I only can accsess the website from the mac mini. The website is not public for other devices then the mac mini. And I'm not getting any error messages.

I checked if there was a hostfile available and there was one.

So my question is if anyone might know what causing that.

Domain is myhouze.se and Ive also set up the IP so it points to the server.

Comment: Did you configure DNS Server ?

Comment: @Jigar The issue has been solved. Turns out it was the nameservers that where configured wrong. Thanks